# Sending header response to the client

Tags: rest, jersey

What is the best way to send the header responses(received from WS call) to the client? I am using Jersey client to call WS and get the response. I was able to send the JSONBody by mapping the JSONBody to POJO's using Jackson. I was able to get the headers(see below code). My question is what is the best way to handle the headers and how should I be sending the headers to the client?

```
Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String header : response.getHeaders().keySet()) {
                System.out.println("header output" + header + "Values"
                        + response.getHeaders().get(header));
                String temp = response.getHeaders().get(header).toString();
                responseHeaders.put(header, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `Response` on the server side. With this you can add the headers, along with a bunch of other things. For example

```
return Response.ok(entity).header("..", "..").header("..", "..").build();
```

Have a look at the [`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html), for some other ideas of what you can do.